# How to get a specific value based on adjacent key from a keyless multidimensional array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Consider the following array:

```
$serviceNames =  array(
    0    =>  array(
        'language'    => 'en',
        'value'       => 'something',
        'type'        => 'name',
    ),
    1    =>  array(
        'language'    => 'fi',
        'value'       => 'jotain',
        'type'        => 'name',
    ),
    2    =>  array(
        'language'    => 'sv',
        'value'       => 'någonting',
        'type'        => 'name',
    ),
);
```

I need to get the 'value' definitions based on language. The problematic part is that the array `$serviceNames` does not have a predefined length (comes originally as a JSON file from an API), and the items can come in any order (in my example it goes like en, fi, sv, but it could be de, en, sv, fr... you get it).

If I wanted to get 'value' within the array where 'language' equals to 'en', how could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice is that you make the array associative.
Once that is done you access the value by `["language"]["value"]`.

```
$serviceNames = array_column($serviceNames, Null, "language");

echo $serviceNames["fi"]["value"];  //jotain
echo $serviceNames["en"]["value"];  //something
echo $serviceNames["sv"]["value"];  //någonting
```

https://3v4l.org/ssGQa

Comment: yes this is the nice way to overcome OP problem, better among the all answer

Comment: @BunkerBoy Thank you!

Comment: Agreed with @Bunker Boy, this is a very clean and efficient way to deal with this code

Comment: @Igsu feel free to accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

simple:

```
$serviceNames =  array(
0 =>  array(
    'language'    => 'en',
    'value'       => 'something',
    'type'        => 'name',
),
1 =>  array(
    'language'    => 'fi',
    'value'       => 'jotain',
    'type'        => 'name',
),
2 =>  array(
    'language'    => 'sv',
    'value'       => 'någonting',
    'type'        => 'name',
),
);
function myfunction(array $serviceNames, $field)
{
   foreach($serviceNames as $service)
   {
      if ( $service['language'] === $field )
         return $service['value'];
   }
   return false;
}
echo myfunction($serviceNames, 'en');
```

Output will : `something`

Answer (score 1):

You can `array_search()` and `array_column()` function. first find the key where "en" is in the array then get the value.

```
$key = array_search('en', array_column($serviceNames, 'language'));
echo $serviceNames[$key]['value'];
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/URQJV)

Answer (score 0):

you would have to go through each elements of the array, using the `foreach` statement.

something like:

```
function getValueForLang($lang, array $arr)
{ 

    foreach ($arr as $desc) {
        if ($desc['language'] == $lang) {
            return $arr['value'];
        }
    }
    return null;
 }
 getValueForLang('en', $serviceNames); // gets your value, null if not found
```

see also:

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: You have two mistakes.  1) `return $arr['value']` not `return $arr['language']`. 2) the `return null` in the `foreach` loop will stop the loop after the first iteration.